# Error deserializing JSON (string / base64)?

Tags: c#, string, encoding, utf-8, base64

I would like to load a string that was saved as a base64, but I always get this error. I am using the SimpleJson class (http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) :

> Exception: Error deserializing JSON. Unknown tag: 66
>   SimpleJSON.JSONNode.Deserialize (System.IO.BinaryReader aReader) (at Assets/plugins/SimpleJSON.cs:512)

My code :

```
var I = new JSONClass();
I["author"]["name"] = "testName";
I["author2"]["name2"] = "testName2";
string str = I.SaveToCompressedBase64();
//output : QlpoOTFBWSZTWdFZTaIAAAdNgH/gEAAA etc.

//#Error deserializing JSON
string res = JSONClass.LoadFromBase64( str );//.ToString();
```

Here are the methods from the class :

```
public static JSONNode LoadFromBase64(string aBase64)
        {
            var tmp = System.Convert.FromBase64String(aBase64);
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(tmp);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return LoadFromStream(stream);
        }

public static JSONNode LoadFromStream(System.IO.Stream aData)
        {
            using(var R = new System.IO.BinaryReader(aData))
            {
                return Deserialize(R);
            }
        }


public static JSONNode Deserialize(System.IO.BinaryReader aReader)
        {
            JSONBinaryTag type = (JSONBinaryTag)aReader.ReadByte();
            switch(type)
            {
            case JSONBinaryTag.Array:
            {
                int count = aReader.ReadInt32();
                JSONArray tmp = new JSONArray();
                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    tmp.Add(Deserialize(aReader));
                return tmp;
            }
            case JSONBinaryTag.Class:
            {
                int count = aReader.ReadInt32();                
                JSONClass tmp = new JSONClass();
                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    string key = aReader.ReadString();
                    var val = Deserialize(aReader);
                    tmp.Add(key, val);
                }
                return tmp;
            }
            case JSONBinaryTag.Value:
            {
                return new JSONData(aReader.ReadString());
            }
            case JSONBinaryTag.IntValue:
            {
                return new JSONData(aReader.ReadInt32());
            }
            case JSONBinaryTag.DoubleValue:
            {
                return new JSONData(aReader.ReadDouble());
            }
            case JSONBinaryTag.BoolValue:
            {
                return new JSONData(aReader.ReadBoolean());
            }
            case JSONBinaryTag.FloatValue:
            {
                return new JSONData(aReader.ReadSingle());
            }

            default:
            {
                throw new Exception("Error deserializing JSON. Unknown tag: " + type);
            }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to parse a compressed string. Try uncompressing the base64 string before trying to parse it.

Comment: @rdodev thanks, could you tell me how to do it? I try `var base64 = System.Convert.FromBase64String(str);` but it does not seem to be the way to do it.

Comment: My answer below should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are trying to save to a compressedbase64string here:

`string str = I.SaveToCompressedBase64();`

which is giving you trouble when you try to parse it and uncompress it. So, I suggest you use their `SaveToBase64()` as follows"

`string str = I.SaveToBase64();`

And leave the rest of your program unchanged (unless there's another error there I didn't see).

Another approach is to use their `LoadFromCompressedBase64()`, so your code would look the same with the exception of:

`string res = JSONClass.LoadFromCompressedBase64( str );//.ToString();`

Comment: Perfect! I was close :) I did not pay attention to the "compressed" in the method, very nice, thank you!